# Can't get Element to work with Sphere

Tags: regions

Mathematica returns

> `False`

when I execute

```
Element[{0, 0, 0}, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]]
```

whereas

```
 Element[{0, 0, 0}, Cuboid[]]
```

returns `True` as expected. Any clue why this could be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Sphere` is a two-dimensional object:

```
RegionDimension[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]]
(* 2 *)
```

so its center is not included in the defined region. Only the shell is considered:

```
Element[Normalize@{1, 1, 1}, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]]
(* True *)
```

You can use `Ball` instead:

```
RegionDimension[Ball[{0, 0, 0}]]
(* 3 *)

Element[{0, 0, 0}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: (+1) Another way to see sphere is not a solid is `In[102]:= Refine[RegionMember[Sphere[], {x, y, z}], Element[{x,y,z}, Reals]]

Out[102]= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1`

Comment: Ah, this clears it up, thanks.